Rest Debugger on OpenAI API
I have integrated an OpenAI API using the Rest Debugger tool on Delphi. But when I run the project, it says Microsoft access denied to that unit, so it must have something to do with the code.
This is the line of code that the debugger flags:
function TJSONArray.GetValue(const Index: Integer): TJSONValue;
begin
  Result := FElements[Index];

I followed a tutorial and did the same code as them. Here is my code, I have '//' in front of a lot of lines of code because I am making sure I am not asking Delphi to do the same thing twice and am rejigging a bit:
Here is my code:
unit AIAPI;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, REST.Types, Vcl.StdCtrls, REST.Client,
  Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope, System.JSON,
  REST.Authenticator.Simple;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    lbl1: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    SimpleAuthenticator1: TSimpleAuthenticator;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
 
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}




procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
jValue:TJSONValue;
JSONData: string;
JSONObject: TJSONOBject;
ChoicesArray: TJSONArray;
MessageObject: TJSONObject;
MyQ,ContentValue: string;
begin
MyQ:= Memo2.Text;
//RESTRequest1.params[0].Value:= 'Bearer API KEY';
//RESTRequest1.params[1].Value:=
//' {"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "'+myQ+' "}], '+ '"temperature": 0.7}';
RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://api.openai.com';  // Set the base URL correctly
RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
RESTRequest1.Response := RESTResponse1;
RESTClient1.Accept := 'application/json';
RESTRequest1.Client := RestClient1;
RESTRequest1.Response := RestResponse1;
RESTRequest1.Resource := '/v1/chat/completions';
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization', 'Bearer API KEY',
    TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json',
    TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.AddBody(
    '{"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "' + MyQ + '"}], "temperature": 0.7}',
    TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON
  );
RESTRequest1.Execute;
JSONData :=RESTResponse1.JSONText;
JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONData) as TJSONObject;
//RestClient1 := RestClient1.Create(nil);
//RestRequest1 := RestRequest1.Create(nil);
//RestResponse1 := RestResponse1.Create(nil);



try
//RestClient1.BaseURL := 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
//RestClient1.Accept := 'application/json';
//RestRequest1.Client := RestClient1;
//RestRequest1.Response := RestResponse1;
//RestRequest1.Resource := '/v1/chat/completions';
//RestRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization', ' Bearer API KEY');
//RestRequest1.AddParameter('body2229D9DFBD044318A4C152D0FDD623AC', '{"model": "gpt-4o-mini","messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}],"temperature": 0}');
ChoicesArray := JSONObject.GetValue('choices') as TJSONArray;
MessageObject := ChoicesArray.Items[0].GetValue<TJSONObject> ('message') as TJSONObject;
ContentValue := MessageObject.GetValue('content').Value;
Memo1.lines.Add('instruction: '+Memo1.Text);
Memo1.lines.Add('Response: '+#13);
Memo1.lines.Add(ContentValue);

finally
RestClient1.Free;
RestRequest1.free;
RestResponse1.Free;
JSONObject.Free;
end;
end;

end.


When asking a question related to code, the very first tag you should add is for the language that you're using. It should not be stated in the title, or in the post body. Tags not only help get the question in front of the people who can answer it, but also help future users find it when searching. I've added it for you.
